# MSBUILD publish ERROR_USER_UNAUTHORIZED

Tags: msbuild, gitlab, publish, gitlab-ci, continuous-delivery

### Summary

I'm using a 9.2.0 Gitlab's CI multirunner on a Windows Server 2016. On a step where I publish ASP.NET project through MSBUILD I've got an authentication error `ERROR_USER_UNAUTHORIZED` from IIS. But when I use a `CMD` window on a build machine there I run the same command for publish - everything is published. Doesn't matter if I used a `SYSTEM` or an `ADMINISTRATOR` account.

### Steps to reproduce

1. Setup IIS publish.
2. Setup Gitlab's build agent.
3. Create the Gitlab's YAML build script (see below).
4. Run the build.

### Actual behavior

On a publish step I've got the `ERROR_USER_UNAUTHORIZED` error.

### Expected behavior

On a publish step I've got my ASP.NET published to a server.

### Relevant logs and/or screenshots

```
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(4292,5): msdeploy error ERROR_USER_UNAUTHORIZED: Не удалось выполнить задачу Web Deploy. (Выполнено подключение к удаленному компьютеру ("192.168.1.66") с использованием службы веб-управления, но не удалось авторизовать. Убедитесь, что вы используете правильные имя пользователя и пароль, что существует сайт, к которому выполняется подключение, и что учетные данные представляют пользователя, у которого есть разрешения на доступ к сайту.  Дополнительные сведения: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_USER_UNAUTHORIZED.) [C:\Gitlab_Build_Agents\1\builds\2378ccf8\0\rushydro\aisa\Sources\Mvc\Mvc.csproj]
```

### Environment description

I'm using a shared Runner (gitlab-ci-multi-runner-windows-386, version 9.2.0) on a Windows 2016. MSBUILD is a part of a Microsoft Visual Studio 2017.

### YAML script

```
variables:
  solution: Sources\Faso.sln
  msbuild: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe
  nunit: C:\NUnit\NUnit.Framework-3.7.0\bin\net-4.5\nunitlite-runner.exe
  nuget: C:\NuGet\nuget.exe

before_script:
  - echo Setting encoding...
  - echo %solution%
  - echo Restoring NuGet packages...
  - '"%nuget%" restore "%solution%"'

stages:
  - build-test
  - deploy-5023

build-test:
  stage: build-test
  script:  
  - chcp 65001
  - echo Building...
  - '"%msbuild%" "%solution%" /t:Build /p:Configuration=Release /p:TargetFramework=v4.5.2'
  - echo Testing...
  - dir /s /b *.Tests.dll | findstr /r Tests\\*\\bin\\ > testcontainers.txt
  - 'for /f %%f in (testcontainers.txt) do "%nunit%" "%%f"'
  except:
  - tags

deploy-5023:
  stage: deploy-5023
  script:
  - chcp 65001
  - echo Deploying...
  - '"%msbuild%" "%solution%" /p:DeployOnBuild=True /p:DeployTarget=MSDeployPublish /p:MsDeployServiceUrl=https://192.168.1.66:8172/msdeploy.axd /p:username=user /p:password=password /p:Configuration=Release /p:TargetFramework=v4.5.2 /p:AllowUntrustedCertificate=True /p:DeployIisAppPath=Faso /p:MSDeployPublishMethod=WMSVC /p:SkipExtraFilesOnServer=True /p:ExcludeFilesFromDeployment="Web.config;ConnectionStrings.config;system.config"'
  when: manual
  except:
  - tags
  artifacts:
    expire_in: 1 week
    paths:
    - Sources\Mvc\App_Data\
    - Sources\Mvc\bin\
    - Sources\Mvc\Content\
    - Sources\Mvc\favicon.ico
    - Sources\Mvc\Global.asax
    - Sources\Mvc\Web.config
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved by changing the arguments' order and format for MSBUILD.

```
- '"%msbuild%" "%solution%" /p:DeployOnBuild=True;Username=username;Password=password;DeployTarget=MSDeployPublish;MsDeployServiceUrl=https://192.168.1.66:8172/msdeploy.axd;Configuration=Release;TargetFramework=v4.5.2;AllowUntrustedCertificate=True;DeployIisAppPath=Faso;MSDeployPublishMethod=WMSVC;SkipExtraFilesOnServer=True;ExcludeFilesFromDeployment="Web.config;ConnectionStrings.config;system.config"'
```

Comment: After lots of hair pulling (publish works in IDE but not commandline) I copy-pasted your command, replaced parameters and it just worked.

Comment: @nurettin another problem was with my password. It contained an exclamation mark (!) and it wasn't correctly translated by CMD and broke the command.

Comment: I also have a password with an exclamation mark, but it doesn't break the commandline (I don't use powershell or bash). Although I understand that password characters can break commands due to past experience with bash.